# Which Zend Server to install on CentOS having PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, centos, zend-server

I have two linux servers

1. CentOS 6.5
2. CentOS 6.6

I have PHP 5.3.3 on these servers

Which version of Zend Server should I install it to these servers?

Comment: I have a Centos 6.6 box running `php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64` & `php-ZendFramework2.noarch`. You can find it in EPEL repo.

Answer (score 1):

I m using Zend Server Community Edition 5.5 with PHP 5.3 on CentOS 6.5. Working fine.You can use Zend Server Community Edition 5.5 if you have php 5.3.

[try this link to install zend server ce](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/content/rpm_installing_zend_server.htm)